# Having different Table space for different indexes of same table, will causes any performance impact?

Tags: oracle, index

Table Master_Table is created in App1_Schema1.
Index_I01 is created in default TABLE SPACE.
Index_I02 is created in TABLE SPACE "APP2_INDEX".

Having different Table space for different indexes of same table, will causes any performance impact ?

Comment: Usually not, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25462668/is-it-good-to-use-default-tablespace-for-high-volume-tables/25465646#25465646

Comment: In the Middle Ages of computing, when servers had individually addressable disk drives, people needed to balance I/O by manually distributing data files to different spindles. But this is 2018. We are using intelligent storage systems with striping and mirroring, and placing files on different spindles is just no longer possible and makes no sense.

Comment: That does not mean that distributing tables and indexes to specific tablespaces is no longer important. It is but for administrative and storage lifecycle reasons. Like having HR tables in one tablespace. Or partitioning tables and indexes by transaction dates into different tablespaces so that older data can easily be moved to cheaper storage ... And that current data can be backed up selectively...

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want to optimize performance? Or do you just want to structure your application?

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind - I think that even in the Dark Ages, trying to physically separeate indexes and tables onto separate disks was a myth.  Consider that given a table access by index the I/O on the index has to be completed (thus releasing the R/W head for other uses) before it is even known where to go get the data that was pointed to by the index.  It is inherently impossible for there to be contention between reading an index and the subsequent read of data based on the results of the index read.

Comment: True dat. So many weird "best practices" have been floating around and still surface as urban legends. Like the one that wants to achieve perfect caching and 100% buffer cache hit.

Comment: @EdStevens That is true and I remember there even was a metalink article that pointed this out. But assume there are a lot of concurrent sessions doing repeatedly such kind of access. Then the IO of these sessions is distributed over both tablespaces.

Comment: @miracle173 - any potential delays due to i/o contention resulting from concurrent sessions in a multi-user system are going to be from a specific usage pattern, and not just a result of having indexes and tables on the same TS.  And if you've got a multi-user system, you're going to have a more complex multi-disk management system, further obliterating any possible impact attributable solely to having indexes and tables in the same TS. You might be able to describe a very specific case, but it would never justify/support the old myth.

Answer (score 1):

Placing the indexes for a table in the same or different tablespaces from the tables and other indexes on the same table should have no impact on performance unless you have done something very wrong with your disk farm.

Comment: One of a few minor advantages with having indexes on a separate tablespace is you could exclude that tablespace from backups, assuming you have scripts available to recreate the indexes.